# What's the result of HQL select from an interface which have two implemented classes

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a interface named `Customer`, These two classes `CustomerImpl` AND `OwnerCustomerImpl` both implemented this interface, then I have a HQL like `"select customer from Customer customer where customer.username=:username"`, so what's result of this HQL?

I always get objects of `CustomerImpl`, but I really want to get `OwnerCustomerImpl`.

I also read doc like:

> 14.8. Polymorphic queries
>
> A query like:
>
> from Cat as cat
>
> returns instances not only of Cat, but also of subclasses like DomesticCat. Hibernate queries can name any Java class or interface in the from clause. The query will return instances of all persistent classes that extend that class or implement the interface. The following query would return all persistent objects:
>
> from java.lang.Object o
>
> The interface Named might be implemented by various persistent classes:
>
> from Named n, Named m where n.name = m.name
>
> These last two queries will require more than one SQL SELECT. This means that the order by clause does not correctly order the whole result set. It also means you cannot call these queries using Query.scroll().

As I think, the result should include both these two classes, so does anybody can help to explain this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to Hibernate, both `CustomerImpl` and `OwnerCustomerImpl` instances should be returned. Check if you have persisted instances for both of those classes.

Also check if you really implement the same `Customer` interface (and not one from another package).

Also check if the result is not a complete list (e.g. just the first X elements) because if the result is limited, as quoted by you Hibernate may choose to return `CustomerImpl` instances first that meet your criteria and include `OwnerCustomerImpl` after that.

Also it could be you simply don't have any `OwnerCustomerImpl` persisted instances that match your query condition.

Comment: Thank you very much icza!

I have checked all things that you talked, they all set correctly. and I also debug the codes, the list of result just include one object is CustomerImpl.

Comment: And I want to let you know, the OwnerCustomerImpl is really extend the CustomerImpl and implement Customer withnew filed named "message", like " public class OwnerCustomerImpl extends CustomerImpl implements Customer", and the strategy is "@Inheritance(strategy="InheritanceType.JOINED)", so there is a table named "customer" in DB, and another table named " owner_customer" just include one column "message", and there is foreign key (customer_id) between those tables, so do you think this is the reason for the problem?

Comment: hello icza, could you please give me more help for this problem? thanks!

Comment: @johnson I do not know if `InheritanceType.JOINED` is the problem, but why don't you just try out with `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`?